# JavaFX - Deployed Application doesn't run on other PCs?

Tags: java, deployment, javafx, public, self-contained

I have a problem with getting the Application to run on other People's machines.

I have tested a self contained and the normal .jar file.
When i pass them to a friend of mine who has java installed, when he opens the .jar file, there is an Error: "Java Exception has occured".

When i run both the .jar and the .exe off the self contained one, both do work on my PC.

So the actual question is:
Why isn't it working just like that?

Can't i just run JavaFX applications without installing the whole JDK?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide any additional info?

Comment: `Can't i just run JavaFX applications without installing the whole JDK` - **You can't**. Either you package the jre with the application or install it prior to executing your app. Can you run your app using `java -jar App.jar` and see the error that is been thrown by the JRE ?

Comment: Hey thanks. When I type your command using Admin Rights, the App starts on my PC. As when my friend does it, it won't work.

So you mean the Self-Contained Application should work without Java even beeing installed on the User's PC?

Can you give me a hint or something how I can "package the jre with the application"?

@Kao what kind of information? I got Netbeans 8.0 with JavaFX installed from the latest JDK. Also I am using the Scene Builder to Design my Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7 there exists the "javafxpackager", [renamed to "javapackager" on Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) which uses some xml-configuration for generating your wanted "Installer"/distribution-package.

As this does not fit some peoples need, there exists a way to use maven:
the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin), you can find [some examples about the usage](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it) of that plugin as linked.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.